# Is it possible to use dyplr for an inner join with a between statement?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

Can somebody give me an example where I can code this SQL in R by using dplyr or another package?

```
select *
from Data
inner join Data2
on Data2.x between Data2.y - 3 and Data2.y + 3
```

Comment: You can do a cross join by using `full_join` with `by=character()` and then `filter` it down but it is very inefficient.  Best to use some other package such as sqldf or data.table.

Comment: If you had some example data frames and desired output it'd be easier because I'm not entirely sure what your query returns, but have you tried something like this: `df1 %>%
  inner_join(
    df2 %>%
      filter(x >= y - 3 && x <= y + 3)
  )`

Comment: See the dupe-links. Long-story-short, `dplyr` does not support join on ranges/overlaps, but `data.table`, `sqldf`, and `fuzzyjoin` all do, and the latter works fluidly in a `dplyr`-pipe.

Comment: (Let me know if I misunderstood your question, but I think the dupe-links should resolve your needs.)

Comment: Thanks to G.Grothendieck. sqldf is a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584557/mutate-a-variable-with-a-few-conditions